# Simple C# Http/TCP Server

Tags: c#, http, sockets, tcp

I am trying to implement a simple http csharp server which sends a document such as index.html to a the browser when the user connects by connecting via the server IP. I am currently a little confused about how i would go about sending a simple .html document over the web browser so the connecting user can see it.

The outstream is where all the information is being sent to the browser.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace TCP_Socket
{
    class ConnectionThread
    {
        public ConnectionThread(Socket socketToHandleConnection)
        {
            connection = socketToHandleConnection;
        }

        Socket        connection       = null;   //TCP/IP socket to handle the actual connection
        NetworkStream connectionStream = null;
        BinaryReader  inStream         = null;
        BinaryWriter  outStream        = null;
        String        userName         = null;

        public void run()
        {
            connectionStream = new NetworkStream(connection);

            inStream  = new BinaryReader(connectionStream);
            outStream = new BinaryWriter(connectionStream);

            userName = Environment.UserName;

            byte b = 0;
            String s = "";      //This will contain all the stuff the browser transmitted,
                                //but "all in one go".
            try
            {
                while (connectionStream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    b = (byte)inStream.ReadSByte();
                    Console.Out.Write((char)b);
                    s += (char)b;
                }

                String[] items = s.Split();//This will contain all the stuff the browser transmitted,


            }
            catch (EndOfStreamException eos)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Unexpected end of stream.");
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Error caused by " + eos.Message);
            }
            Console.Out.WriteLine("End of stream.");

            String stringOut = "HTTP/ 1.1 200 OK\r\n";
            outStream.Write(stringOut.ToCharArray());

            stringOut = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
            outStream.Write(stringOut.ToCharArray());

            stringOut = "Date: ";
            outStream.Write(stringOut.ToCharArray());
            stringOut = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
            outStream.Write(stringOut.ToCharArray());   
            stringOut = "\r\n";
            outStream.Write(stringOut.ToCharArray());

            stringOut = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">\r\n";
            outStream.Write(stringOut.ToCharArray());

            stringOut = "<html>\r\n";
            outStream.Write(stringOut.ToCharArray());

            stringOut = "<body>\r\n";
            outStream.Write(stringOut.ToCharArray());

            stringOut = "Welcome to <strong>" + userName + "'s </strong>primative HTTP server";
            outStream.Write(stringOut.ToCharArray());

            stringOut = "</body></html>\r\n";
            outStream.Write(stringOut.ToCharArray());

            inStream.Close();
            outStream.Flush();
            outStream.Close();
            connectionStream.Close();
            connection.Close();

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Done; Connection closed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to write all of HTTP code using sockets as [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is already provided from .NET 2.0. give it a try if it fits your requirements.

Comment: The downside with HttpListener is you have to run something in the OS before it will let you accept connections i.e.

netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user

Comment: any alternate solution ? i have some problem work with httplistener

Comment: HttpListner also no go in windows server 2019. It cant be access via lan only by localhost.

Answer (score 2):

after searching i found some other solutions:

Other similar embeddable servers include:

- [Sample HTTP Server Skeleton in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17071/Sample-HTTP-Server-Skeleton-in-C)
- [Embedded .NET HTTP Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25050/Embedded-NET-HTTP-Server)
- [System.Net HttpListener (as of .NET Framework 3.5 SP1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)
- [The HTTP server provided in zeroconf.codeplex.com](http://zeroconf.codeplex.com/)
- [Simple HTTP Server in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C)